# Call function in vector of 2 class inheritance

Tags: c++

I'm getting into polysorphism. I'm in trouble with vector when I call function. This is my code:

```
Class Customer: 


#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class Customer
{
protected:
    string id;
    float money;
public:
    Customer();
    ~Customer();
    virtual void Input();
    virtual void Output();
    string GetId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    void SetId(string ID)
    {
        id = ID;
    }
};
```

Class LoyalCustomer:

```
#pragma once
#include"Customer.h"
class LoyalCustomer:public Customer
{
    int level;  //level of relationship
public:
    LoyalCustomer();
    ~LoyalCustomer();
    void Input();
    void Output();
};
```

RegularCustomer:

```
#pragma once
class RegularCustomer:public Customer
{
public:
    RegularCustomer();
    ~RegularCustomer();
    void Input();
    void Output();
};
```

Class SuperMarket:

```
#pragma once
#include"LoyalCustomer.h"
#include"RegularCustomer.h"
class SuperMarket
{
    vector<Customer*> list;
public:
    SuperMarket();
    ~SuperMarket();
    void FindCustomer()
    {
        string ID;
        cout << "Input id of customer: ";
        cin >> ID;
        for (int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++)
            if (ID == list[i]->GetId())
            {
                //do something
            }
    }
    void Input()
    {
        string ID;
        cout << "Input id of customer: ";
        cin >> ID;
        Customer *p = NULL;
        if (ID[0] == 'L')
        {
            p = new LoyalCustomer;
            p->Input();
            p->SetId(ID);
            list.push_back(p);
        }
        if (ID[0] == 'R')
        {
            p = new RegularCustomer;
            p->Input();
            p->SetId(ID);
            list.push_back(p);
        }
    }
    void Output()
    {
        //printf customer 
    }
};
```

When I call GetID() function in FindCustomer() function in line:if (ID == list[i]->GetId()) and then I run my code, program doesn't notify error but I input "ID" to find, it doesn't find out. I don't know how to fix it. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: the program is running right? and did you make sure the list is not empty?

Comment: Rather than a setter for ID consider using ID as a parameter for the constructor.

Comment: Please describe your problem more clearly. It doesn't work, how? It doesn't not return anything or the comparison have trouble? the destructor should be virtual, too. 


And your Input/Output function in LoyalCustomer/RegularCustomer breaks the rule of inheritance by shallowing Input/Output function in Customer. It should override the virtual in the base class by virtual keyword. Also, I didn't see the body of these function in Customer, why don't set them pure virtual.

Comment: Recommend placing a debugger breakpoint in `GetID` to confirm that you never get there. Recommend using the debugger in general. Save you a lot of time.

Comment: What does "doesn't run" mean, is it a compile or runtime error? What is the error? etc... Also why are you pushing pointers? It just makes for extra work and the code less safe, and at least from the shown code, you've got a memory leak.

Answer (score -1):

Try compare string like `ID.compare(list[i]->GetId()) == 0`

Comment: The `==` operator is overloaded in `std::string`